# 3D tree in Mathematica?

Tags: programming, graphics3d, algorithm, fractals

Searching the web for information about the affine transformation, I found the one page, which called my attention for the tree that show and is this

[image: tree]

but unfortunately do not give information about the algorithm to create it, I would like to ask help to make one the same or very similar, maybe someone knows where to get more information about it. Thanks in advance, here is the [link to the page](https://hiveminer.com/Tags/binary,tree/Interesting) mentioned above

Comment: [This](http://blog.wolfram.com/2014/05/22/adventures-into-the-mathematical-forest-of-fractal-trees/) and [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960077906003894).

Comment: @ corey979 Thank you very much for the information, read it with great attention to understand the methods for the generation of this type of graphics.

Comment: In case you don't know, it's common courtesy to link to [the corresponding Community question](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1168243) if you ask something here and at Community. (Likewise, if you post there, link to your question here.)

Comment: I want to apologize to everyone for not putting the link that leads to the community as you suggest, I really did not know, but I will not forget, greetings.

Comment: You might be interested in so-called "algorithmic botany" or "computational botany".

Comment: @Silvia Thank you very much for the information, I will start looking for more about this exciting topic

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First, an idomatic, but slow version.

```
s1 = 1/GoldenRatio // N;
s2 = 1/GoldenRatio // N;
stem = {0., 0., 1.};
thickness = 0.15;
branches = Table[RotationMatrix[2. k Pi/3., {0, 0, 1}].{Cos[Pi/4.], 0., Sin[Pi/4.]}, {k, 0, 2}];
data0 = {Join[{{0., 0., 0.}}, {stem}, branches, {{thickness, 1., 0.}}]};
iteration[data_] :=
 Block[{U},
  Flatten[Table[
    U = data[[j]];
    Table[
     Join[{U[[1]] + U[[2]]}, {U[[i]]}, 
      s1 U[[3 ;; 5]].RotationMatrix[{U[[i]], U[[2]]}], {s2 U[[6]]}],
     {i, 3, 5}],
    {j, 1, Length[data]}
    ],
   1
   ]
  ]
```

This generates the tree structure.

```
result = NestList[iteration, data0, 6]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.211536, Null} *)
```

This generates the tree plot.

```
t = 0.5;
colfun[x_] := ColorData["Rainbow"][t + (1 - t) x];
plot[U_] := {colfun[U[[6, 2]]],Table[Sphere[U[[1]] + t U[[2]], U[[6, 1]] (1 - t) + t s2 U[[6, 1]]], {t, 0.0, 0.9, 0.1}]};
Graphics3D[
 Flatten[plot /@ Flatten[result, 1]],
 Lighting -> "Neutral",
 Background -> Black,
 Boxed -> False,
 SphericalRegion -> True
 ]
```

[image]

A faster version is generated with `Compile` and some handcraft:

```
citeration2 = 
  With[{scale1 = s1, scale2 = s2, part = Compile`GetElement},
   Compile[{{U, _Real, 2}}, Block[{A, u, v, w},
     v = {part[U, 2, 1], part[U, 2, 2], part[U, 2, 3]}/Sqrt[part[U, 2, 1]^2 + part[U, 2, 2]^2 + part[U, 2, 3]^2];
     Table[
      u = {part[U, i, 1], part[U, i, 2], part[U, i, 3]}/Sqrt[part[U, i, 1]^2 + part[U, i, 2]^2 + part[U, i, 3]^2];
      w = {
        -(part[u, 3] part[v, 2]) + part[u, 2] part[v, 3],
        part[u, 3] part[v, 1] - part[u, 1] part[v, 3],
        -(part[u, 2] part[v, 1]) + part[u, 1] part[v, 2]
        };
      w = {part[w, 1], part[w, 2], part[w, 3]}/Sqrt[part[w, 1]^2 + part[w, 2]^2 + part[w, 3]^2];
      A = {
        {
         part[u, 1] part[v, 1] + part[w, 1]^2 + (part[u, 3] part[w, 2] - part[u, 2] part[w, 3]) (part[v, 3] part[w, 2] - part[v, 2] part[w, 3]),
         part[u, 2] part[v, 1] + part[w, 1] part[w, 2] + (-(part[u, 3] part[w, 1]) + part[u, 1] part[w, 3]) (part[v, 3] part[w, 2] - part[v, 2] part[w, 3]), 
         part[u, 3] part[v, 1] + part[w, 1] part[w, 3] + (part[u, 2] part[w, 1] - part[u, 1] part[w, 2]) (part[v, 3] part[w, 2] - part[v, 2] part[w, 3])
         }, {
         part[u, 1] part[v, 2] + part[w, 1] part[w, 2] + (part[u, 3] part[w, 2] - part[u, 2] part[w, 3]) (-(part[v, 3] part[w, 1]) + part[v, 1] part[w, 3]),
         part[u, 2] part[v, 2] + part[w, 2]^2 + (-(part[u, 3] part[w, 1]) + part[u, 1] part[w, 3]) (-(part[v, 3] part[w, 1]) + part[v, 1] part[w, 3]),
         part[u, 3] part[v, 2] + part[w, 2] part[w, 3] + (part[u, 2] part[w, 1] - part[u, 1] part[w, 2]) (-(part[v, 3] part[w, 1]) + part[v, 1] part[w, 3])
         }, {
         part[u, 1] part[v, 3] + part[w, 1] part[w, 3] + (part[v, 2] part[w, 1] - part[v, 1] part[w, 2]) (part[u, 3] part[w, 2] - part[u, 2] part[w, 3]),
         part[u, 2] part[v, 3] + part[w, 2] part[w, 3] + (part[v, 2] part[w, 1] - part[v, 1] part[w, 2]) (-(part[u, 3] part[w, 1]) + part[u, 1] part[w, 3]),
         part[u, 3] part[v, 3] + (part[u, 2] part[w, 1] - part[u, 1] part[w, 2]) (part[v, 2] part[w, 1] - part[v, 1] part[w, 2]) + part[w, 3]^2
         }
        };
      Join[{part[U, 1] + part[U, 2]}, {part[U, i]}, scale1 U[[3 ;; 5]].A, {scale2 part[U, 6]}], {i, 3, 5}]], 
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True,
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
   ];
iteration2[data_] := Flatten[citeration2[data], 1];

result2 = NestList[iteration2, data0, 6]; // AbsoluteTiming
Max[Abs[result2 - result]]

(* {0.001042, Null} *)
(* 1.33227*10^-15 *)

 result3 = NestList[iteration2, data0, 9]; // AbsoluteTiming
 Graphics3D[
  Flatten[plot /@ Flatten[result3, 1]], 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", Background -> Black, 
  Boxed -> False, 
  SphericalRegion -> True
 ]

(* {0.018179, Null} *)
```

[image]

The slow part is the rendering by Mathematica, though...

Comment: What is `getp`?

Comment: Ah. Wait a sec. I am still building on this...

Comment: @J.M. Hm. I guess, it's done. Have a look.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Astonishing, the tree is the same as the one on the website, mentioned separately are the improvements you propose. I am learning more and more with these kinds of answers. Thanks for your answer

Comment: You're welcome! Actually, it was quite some fun!

Comment: I've upvoted now; beautifully done!

Answer (score 10):

Slow version

```
Clear["`*"];

s=1./GoldenRatio;
thickness = 0.15;

next[{a_,b_}]:=Table[{a,b}//TranslationTransform[b-a]//
  RotationTransform[Pi/4,{Cos[2k Pi/3],Sin[2k Pi/3],0},b]//
    ScalingTransform[{1,1,1}s,b],{k,3}];

n=5;

pts=NestList[Join@@next/@#&,N@{{{0,0,0},{0,0,1}}},n];//AbsoluteTiming

Graphics3D[{Tube[Join@@pts,0.02]}]

Graphics3D[MapIndexed[With[{id=#2[[1]]},{ColorData["Rainbow",1-id/10],
  MapIndexed[Sphere[#,t=#2[[1]]/10; k=thickness s^id;k(1-t) + t  k s]&,
    Subdivide[#[[1]],#[[2]],9]]}]&,pts,{2}]]
```

Faster version

```
Clear["`*"];

s=1./GoldenRatio;
thickness = 0.15;

next=Table[{a,b}//TranslationTransform[b-a]//
 RotationTransform[Pi/4,{Cos[2k Pi/3],Sin[2k Pi/3],0},b]//
   ScalingTransform[{1,1,1}s,b],{k,3}]/.
     Thread[{a,b}->Table[Indexed[A,{x,y}],{x,2},{y,3}]]/.
        expr_:>Compile[{{A,_Real,2}},
           expr,RuntimeAttributes->{Listable} ];

n=9;

pts=MapIndexed[Flatten[#,#2[[1]]-1]&,NestList[next,N@{{{0,0,0},{0,0,1}}},n]];//AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0085782, Null} *)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]