# Elegant implementation of factorial tree graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, trees

Consider the tree graph used in part of my solution to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3020533/geometrical-interpretation-for-the-sum-of-factorial-numbers/3020537#3020537):

[image: Factorial tree graph]

Each level $i$ has $i!$ nodes, and the branching ratio is $i+1$:

I kludged together code to generate this graph (with code better left un-reproduced).

Is there an elegant method for generating such a tree graph for arbitrary number of levels?

A three-dimensional layout might look like this:

[image]

but I'd prefer a better embedding at the higher-$n$ levels, closer to this:

[image]

Comment: @J42161217 Fixed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

here is my elegant implementation

```
l[c_]:=TakeList[Range@Sum[k!,{k,c}],Range@c!][[c-1]];
T[x_]:=Graph[(F=Flatten)@Table[MapThread[#->#2&,{Sort@F@Table[l@i,i],l[i+1]}],{i,2,x+1}]];

T@3
```

which returns

[image]

but if your Mathematica version doesn't support `TakeList` here is another way

```
s[x_] := Sum[k!,{k,x}];
z[y_] := Partition[Range[s@y+1,s[y+1]],1+y];
v[n_] := Table[{Flatten[z[n-1]][[i]]->z[n][[i,j]]},{i,n!},{j,n+1}];
tree[t_] := Graph[Flatten[Array[v@#&,t],3]];

tree@3
```

[image]

```
tree@6
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice (+1).  I would add only `Embedding -> "RadialEmbedding"` to your code.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork updated with a new approach

Comment: Now *THAT* is elegant!  (accept)  Thanks so much!  I'm now working on getting a clear three-dimensional embedding (see revised question).

Answer (score 31):

**Update 3:** [`ExpressionGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpressionGraph.html) is now available in version 12.1.

**Update 2:** a more streamlined  version for 2D graphs:

```
ClearAll[g]
g = GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph[ConstantArray[x, #], VertexLabels -> None] &;
```

Examples:

```
g[Range[2, 4]]
```

[image]

```
SetProperty[g[{3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4}],
  {GraphLayout -> "RadialEmbedding", EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line"}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[f]
f[g_: Graph][n_List, o : OptionsPattern[]] := g[UndirectedEdge @@@ EdgeList@
    GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph[ConstantArray[x, n]], 
     o, GraphLayout -> {"BalloonEmbedding"}, ImageSize -> Large]
f[g_: Graph][n_Integer, o : OptionsPattern[]] := f[g][Range[2, n], o]
```

**Examples:**

```
f[][6]
```

[image]

```
f[][6, GraphLayout -> {"RadialEmbedding"}]
```

[image]

```
g1 = f[Graph3D][6]
```

[image]

```
g2 = f[Graph3D][6, GraphLayout -> {"RadialEmbedding"}]
```

[image]

Use a list for number of vertices on each layer as the argument:

```
f[][{3, 5, 2, 4}, GraphLayout -> {"RadialEmbedding", "LayerSizeFunction" -> (# &)}]
```

[image]

**Update:** ***... to take the Graph3D and somehow improve the layout on the high-n layers: There seems to be lots of wasted space.***

One way to change the box ratios without distorting the vertex shapes is to modify the `VertexCoordinates` using `ScalingTransform`:

```
SetProperty[g1, VertexCoordinates -> ScalingTransform[{1, 1, 3}][GraphEmbedding@g1]]
```

[image]

```
SetProperty[g2, VertexCoordinates -> ScalingTransform[{1, 1, 3}][GraphEmbedding@g2]]
```

[image]

Or add the suboption `"LayerSizeFunction"` in  `"RadialEmbedding"`:

```
g3 = f[Graph3D][6, GraphLayout -> {"RadialEmbedding", "LayerSizeFunction" -> (# &)}];
SetProperty[g3, VertexCoordinates -> ScalingTransform[{1, 1, -3}][GraphEmbedding@g3]]
```

[image]

```
SetProperty[#, VertexCoordinates -> ScalingTransform[{1, 1, 3}][GraphEmbedding@#]] &@
 f[Graph3D][{3, 5, 2, 4}, GraphLayout -> {"RadialEmbedding", "LayerSizeFunction"->(#&)}]
```

[image]

Comment: I *knew* you'd come up with something powerful and elegant.  My only suggestion for improvement would be to take the Graph3D and somehow improve the layout on the high-$n$ layers:  There seems to be lots of wasted space.  Other than that... great!  (+1)

Comment: Just wow. That's hardly to top in terms of elegance.

Comment: @David, please see the update.

Comment: David, @HenrikSchumacher, thank you for the upvotes  and kind words.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher:  `l[c_]:=TakeList[Range@Sum[k!,{k,c}],Range@c!][[c-1]];
T[x_]:=Graph[(F=Flatten)@Table[MapThread[#->#2&,{Sort@F@Table[l@i,i],l[i+1]}],{i,2,x+1}]]`; seems incredibly efficient, clever and... yes.. "elegant."  All other implementations include more code or are less elegant (in my humble opinion).  About 1/6 the code in my (non-optimized) implementation.

Comment: I've joined the community just to upvote this answer and those wonderful graphs.

Comment: Thank you @EricDuminil. Welcome to mma.se:)

Answer (score 23):

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) already has this built-in as `IGSymmetricTree`. You can specify the number of branches at each level.

[image]

```
IGSymmetricTree[
 Range[2, 4],
 DirectedEdges -> True,
 GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding"
]
```

[image]

The implementation [is mostly in C](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/blob/master/IGraphM/LibraryResources/Source/IGlobal.h#L267) (not Mathematica) and not from [igraph](http://igraph.org) this time. This is simply easier to implement procedurally, for which C is a good fit. This is why I did not do it in pure WL.

Here's another structure, with a different number of branches at each level.

```
IGSymmetricTree[{5, 4, 3, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is precisely the functionality I need (thanks... +1), but I was hoping for the full code to be available, and (hopefully) clever and elegant.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The full code *is* available (I linked to part of it), it is just not fully in Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks, but I need fully *Mathematica* code.  Perhaps WRI will add this valuable functionality to its next release.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork If they do, I bet they won't implement it in WL :P  The procedural loops I linked to may be not be pretty, but I think they're easy to follow and translate to a few `Table`s with global variables straightforwardly.

Comment: @David I accept that you want WL code, but could you explain why, just to satisfy my interest? People often refuse to use my package "because it's not built in". I do not understand why that is an issue. The package is polished, more robust than most, easy to install, and easy to uninstall without leaving traces. Other than for using the function in the cloud or in a FreeCDF (which is on the way out...) I do not see why having this functionality in a package (instead of built in) would be a problem.

Comment: Sure.  I appreciate your wonderful coding efforts.  However, in many cases I make CDF figures for class presentation and it is simpler to generate such figures without linking to libraries (especially $C$ or $C++$ libraries).  Also, I understand and can thus modify *Mathematica* code better.  Why not write all the code in *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 15):

I don't know if you find this elegant. But I give it a try.

```
maxdepth = 5;
Graph[
 Transpose[{
   Join @@ MapIndexed[
     {x, i} \[Function] Join @@ Transpose[ConstantArray[Range @@ x, (i + 1)]], 
     Join[{{1}}, Partition[Accumulate[Range[maxdepth - 1]!], 2, 1] + ConstantArray[{1, 0}, maxdepth - 2]]
     ],
   Range[2, Total[Range[maxdepth]!]]
   }],
 DirectedEdges -> True,
 GraphLayout -> "BalloonEmbedding"
 ]
```

[image]

## Edit

Out of curiosity, I adapted the algorithm above to produce also other symmetric trees.

```
SymmetricTree[branchlist_?(VectorQ[#, IntegerQ] &)] := 
 Module[{levelnodecounts}, 
  levelnodecounts = FoldList[#1 #2 &, 1, branchlist];
  Graph[Transpose[{
     Join @@ MapIndexed[
       {x, i} \[Function] Join @@ Transpose[ConstantArray[Range @@ x, branchlist[[i[[1]]]]]],
       Join[
        {{1}},
        Partition[Accumulate[Most[levelnodecounts]], 2, 1] + ConstantArray[{1, 0}, Length[branchlist] - 1]
        ]
       ],
     Range[2, 1 + Total[Rest[levelnodecounts]]]}], 
   DirectedEdges -> True
   ]
  ]
```

Regarding speed, it seems to be on par with `IGSymmetricTree`. Of course, I cannot provide such a detailed user interface as Szabolcs so I would suggest to use IGraphM whenever possible.

## Edit 2

Adapting my [(slow) code for fractal trees](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154227), here is another way to embedd the tree:

```
BoccoliEmbedding[branchlist_] := 
 Module[{data0, data, θ, stem, thickness, s1, s2, f, F},
  θ = Pi/4.;
  s1 = 1/GoldenRatio // N;
  s2 = 1/GoldenRatio // N;
  stem = {0., 0., 1.};
  thickness = 0.15;
  data0 = {Join[
     {{0., 0., 0.}},
     {stem},
     {{thickness, 1., 0.}},
     Table[
      RotationMatrix[2. k Pi/branchlist[[1]], {0, 0, 1}].{Cos[θ], 0.,Sin[θ]}, 
      {k, 0, branchlist[[1]] - 1}]
     ]
    };
  f = {U, n} \[Function] Table[
     Join[
      {U[[1]] + U[[2]]},
      {U[[i]]},
      {s2 U[[3]]},
      Dot[
       s1 Table[RotationMatrix[2. Pi j/n, U[[2]]].U[[i]], {j, 0, n - 1}], 
       RotationMatrix[{U[[i]], U[[2]]}]
       ]
      ],
     {i, 4, Length[U]}];
  F = {data, n} \[Function] Join @@ (f[#, n] & /@ data);
  data = Join @@ FoldList[F, data0, Join[Rest[branchlist], {1}]];
  data[[All, 1]] + data[[All, 2]]
  ];
```

And this is how we apply it:

```
b = Range[2, 7];
plot = Graph[
  EdgeList[SymmetricTree[b]],
  VertexCoordinates -> BoccoliEmbedding[b]
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Elegant enough! (+1)  `GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding"` works fine for $4$ levels, but not $5$, so your layout choice is probably one of the best.  Before I accept, let me wait to see if someone is clever with specifying vertex *order* or other approach.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful coding... extremely helpful.  I know it wasn't part of my original question, but I've been working on a three-dimensional graph embedding, using `VertexCoordinates`, in which each level $i$ is at a different (stacked) height and the vertices at each height are packed efficiently.  This would be a very cool graphic, and interpretable for $n=7$ or possibly higher!

Answer (score 6):

Based on @kglr's answer, but avoiding the use of undocumented functions (ExpressionGraph):

These trees correspond to the expression structure of a full array of dimensions `{2, 3, 4, ...}` (think `TreeForm`).

To recover this tree, we walk the array expression using `Position` and record the positions of subexpressions. We will use these positions as graph vertices.

The position specification is such that we can always compute the parent node of a position by dropping its last element (implemented as `[[;;-2]]`).   For example, the parent subexpression of a subexpression at position `{2,1}` is found at position `{2}`.

`Position` walks the expression in post-order, meaning that it returns the root vertex (position of full expression, `{}`) last. We reverse the vertex list to get the root as the first vertex instead. Then we drop this root from the edge computation (`MapThread`) as it has no parents.

Finally, we replace vertex names with integer vertex indices using `IndexGraph`.

```
symmetricTree[levels_List] :=
 Module[{vertices, edges},
  vertices = Reverse@Position[ConstantArray[0, levels], _, {0, Infinity}, Heads -> False];
  edges = MapThread[DirectedEdge, {vertices[[2;; , ;;-2]], vertices[[2;;]]}];
  IndexGraph@Graph[v, e]
 ]
```

I find this method clear and readable.

```
symmetricTree[{2, 3, 4}]
```

[image]