# Construct a permutation tree plot

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, visualization, combinatorics, trees

[image]
How to construct a tree like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKYl9.png)? I was looking `CompleteKaryTree` initially, there are some similarities overall, but it's still different.

```
CompleteKaryTree[5, 2, GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding", AspectRatio -> 1/4]
```

[image]

Another way, I've generated the coordinates of all the points, but I don't know how to connect them

```
n=4;
pts=Join @@ Table[{1/2 (1+(n-j)!)+(i-1) (n-j)!,n-j-1},{j,0,n},{i,FactorialPower[n,j]}];
Graphics[{Point@pts}, ImageSize->Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PermutationTree/)? Changing `GraphPlot` to `TreePlot` in the source code gives the requested output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`ExpressionGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpressionGraph.html) to draw the tree

```
expr = ConstantArray[x, Reverse @ Range[4]];

ExpressionGraph[expr, GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding", ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
 epxr2  = ConstantArray[x, Reverse @ Range[5]];

 ExpressionGraph[expr2, GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding", ImageSize -> 700, 
 VertexSize -> Medium, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

Define a function that constructs a permutation tree with edge labels:

```
ClearAll[rule, permutationTree]
rule = # /.  x : {___Integer} /; Length[x] > 1 :>
   (Reverse /@ Subsets[Reverse@x, {Length[x] - 1}]) &;
 
permutationTree[n_, opts : OptionsPattern[Graph]] := 
 Module[{eg = ExpressionGraph[ConstantArray[x, Reverse@Range[n]], 
     opts, GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding", 
     ImageSize -> 700, VertexSize -> Medium, AspectRatio -> 1/2], 
   edgelabels},
  edgelabels =  Thread[First @ Last @ Reap@
        BreadthFirstScan[eg, 1, {"FrontierEdge" -> Sow}] -> 
          Flatten@NestList[rule, Range[n], n - 1]] ; 
  SetProperty[eg, EdgeLabels -> edgelabels]]
```

***Examples:***

```
permutationTree[3]
```

[image]

```
permutationTree[4]
```

[image]

```
permutationTree[4, GraphLayout -> "RadialEmbedding", 
  AspectRatio -> 1, EdgeLabelStyle -> Large]
```

[image]

```
permutationTree[5, ImageSize -> 900]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `TreeForm`:

```
TreeForm[expr,  ImageSize -> Large, VertexLabeling -> False]
```

[image]

***Note:*** For versions older than v12.0, replace `ExpressionGraph` with `` GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph ``. (See also [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/187074/125).)

Answer (score 4):

Using a slight modification of the code in [Wolfram Demonstrations >> Permutation Tree](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PermutationTree/) (linked by George Varnavides in comments) and adding edge labels:

```
ClearAll[permTree]
permTree[n_, opts : OptionsPattern[Graph]] := Module[{el = Union @@ 
 Map[Rule @@@ Partition[FoldList[Append, {}, #], 2, 1] &, Permutations @ Range @ n]},
  Graph[el, opts, DirectedEdges -> False, 
   GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding", EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> e[[2, -1]]}]]
```

***Examples:***

```
permTree[3, ImageSize -> Large, 
   VertexLabels -> {v_ /; Length[v] == 3 :> Placed[Column @ v, Below]}]
```

[image]

```
permTree[4, ImageSize -> 800, 
   VertexLabels -> {v_ /; Length[v] == 4 :> Placed[Column @ v, Below]}]
```

[image]

```
permTree[4, ImageSize -> Large, GraphLayout -> "RadialEmbedding"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In 12.3 or later, you can use NestTree:

```
choice[{_, list_List}]:=
  MapIndexed[{e, pos} |-> {e, Delete[list, pos]}, list]

permutationTree[list_List] :=
  NestTree[choice, {Null, list}, Infinity, First]
permutationTree[n_Integer] :=
  permutationTree[Range[n]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using my package [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM/),

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]
IGSymmetricTree[{4, 3, 2, 1}, GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding"]
```

[image]

See [its documentation](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#igsymmetrictree), which shows precisely the tree you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

We create the points recursively. Given the numbers of siblings in every generation by e.g. `ngen=ngen = {4, 3, 2, 1}`, in a first step we create 4 descendants. Then  for every sibling we create another 3 descendants, then 2, then 1. Finally we use `TreePlot`. You may play with labels, I simply number the edges here:

```
ngen = {4, 3, 2, 1};
p = 0;
Clear[step];
step[n0_, 
  gen_] := (next = 
   Table[n0 \[UndirectedEdge] ++p, ngen[[gen]]]; {next, 
   If[gen == Length@ngen, Nothing[], step[#[[2]], gen + 1] & /@ next]})
tr = step[0, 1];
TreePlot[tr // Flatten(*,0,VertexLabels\[Rule]"Name"*), 
 EdgeLabels -> "Index"]
```

[image]